# suddenly my code is no longer colorful anymore

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

all my codes became in white color in android studio , even the red lines error disappear . there some errors though !

How could i make it back to normal state .

i tried to uninstall dart/flutter plugin . but with no luck

[image]

Comment: Make sure the `Flutter SDK Path` is correct in `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter` in Android Studio

Comment: try running `flutter doctor` command and see if you find something.